# JavaFX, is it better to create UI using java or fxml?

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I will have one element that needs to be added x times depending on input list. Is it better to use java code and add listener to buttons:

```
private void createList(List<House> houses){
        for(House house : houses){
            StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
            Region region = new Region();
            RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton();
            Button button = new Button();

            stackPane.setMinWidth(500);
            stackPane.setMaxWidth(800);
            stackPane.setMaxHeight(40);
            stackPane.setPrefHeight(40);

            region.getStyleClass().add("house-region");
            region.setPrefHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);

            radioButton.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
            radioButton.setText(house.getStreet()+" "+house.getHouseNumber()+", "+house.getPostCode()+", "+house.getCity()+", "+house.getCountry());
            VBox.setMargin(radioButton, new Insets(0, 0, 0, 30));

            button.setPadding(new Insets(0, 15, 0, 15));
            button.setText(Word.translate("delete"));
            button.setPrefHeight(Double.MAX_VALUE);
            button.setMaxHeight(25);
            button.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

            stackPane.getChildren().addAll(region, radioButton, button);
            houseListVBox.getChildren().add(stackPane);
        }
    }
```

Or to have my `StackPane` in separate `fxml` and use corresponding controller:

```
private void createList(List<House> houses){
        for(House house : houses){
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(); //Loads an object hierarchy from an XML document.
            loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource(element)); // which document
            StackPane stackPane = (StackPane) loader.load();
            houseListVBox.getChildren().add(stackPane);
        }
    }
```

Which one is better depending on performance, good practice?

Comment: Why use a `VBox` margin for some node you do not intend to use as the child of the `VBox`?

Answer (score -1):

Oracle do recommend FXML for UI design over the Java API 
specially it uses MVC approach and it can be easily designed using [Scene Builder](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/scenebuilder/1/get_started/jsbpub-get_started.htm), which is a Drag n Drop UI designer for JAVA-FX application.
The Presentation Layer(UI) is segregated from the Application layer(logic), which makes it easy to change the look and feel of the application as and when required. FXML's brings in scalability and maintainability in your applications

**Other Benefits of FXML**

Because the scene graph is more transparent in FXML, it is easy for a development team to create and maintain a testable user interface.
FXML is not a compiled language; you do not need to recompile the code to see the changes.

The content of an FXML file can be localized as the file is read. For example, if an FXML file is loaded using the en_US locale, then it produces the string "First Name" for a label based on the following resource string:

If the locale is changed to fr_FR and the FXML file is reloaded, then the label shows "Prénom."

The same is ***not true*** for ***Java code***, because you must manually update the content of every element of your user interface by obtaining a reference to it and calling the appropriate setter (such as `setText()`).

See oracle recommendation : [Why Use FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/why_use_fxml.htm) and [JavaFX Best Practices](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/best_practices/jfxpub-best_practices.htm)

Comment: All of these things could be done with Java too, though (of course): you can implement MVC, and you can do things like `Label label = new Label(resources.getString(key));` to localize controls from a resource bundle.